# Max for woocommerce attribute VALUES

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am apparently exceeding the maximum characters allowed for the attribute VALUES in woocommerce, and I can't seem to find what the max actually is.

Clients will ultimately be adding products once I do the original set up, so it adding them as custom variables is something I want to avoid.

I also don't want to have to mess with functions; I'm trying to limit the actual values to less then the max.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

The attribute Values will be saved in table (wp)_postmeta,

in the meta_value column (meta_key is _product_attributes).

This column is from **"Longtext"** type.

Longtext from the MYSQL Doc.:

> "A TEXT column with a maximum length of **4,294,967,295 or 4GB (232 – 1) characters**. The effective maximum length is less if the value contains multi-byte characters. The effective maximum length of LONGTEXT columns also depends on the configured maximum packet size in the client/server protocol and available memory."

[Link to MYSQL Doc.](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-type-overview.html)

Woocommerce saves more than this Value in the field.
Here is an example:

```
a:1:{s:4:"attr";a:6:{s:4:"name";s:4:"attr";s:5:"value";s:5:"1 | 2
";s:8:"position";i:0;s:10:"is_visible";
i:1;s:12:"is_variation";i:0;s:11:"is_taxonomy";i:0;}}
```

At the End of the first line you see **1 | 2**, this are my test attribute Values.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem and solved it today so I'm gonna say what I done if someone will search for it again. So you can go to your wp-content / woocommerce / includes / wc-attribute-functions.php and just ctrl + f for 28. There is the max number for your attribute slug. If you want find another places like not slug, but name and etc. just download whole woocommerce folder and search it with editor witch allows you to search for multiple files. But also I'm pretty sure your code changes will be wiped out when you update woocommerce.